# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string when using basename

Tags: shell

code example:
`my PWD = /aa/bb/cc/dd`

```
dir= `dirname "$(PWD)"`
output = `basename "${dir}"`
```

dir variable outputs correctly: `/aa/bb/cc`

desired output variable: `cc`

error I'm getting: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

I've tried different quotation combinations and other things like these suggested solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401091/bash-variable-substitution-vs-dirname-and-basename/22402242 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253524/dirname-and-basename-vs-parameter-expansion

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to _cut and paste_ your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: There's an edit attempt from another user that tries to be `user1094771`. Please see [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1094771/user1094771) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1094780/user1094771). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: The edit was [rejected](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/918204), although [maybe it shouldn't have been](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12690/432690). If it was really you, the author, then don't let this rejection stop you. After you get the accounts merged you will regain the ownership and be able to edit freely. Edit the question again then.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me :

```
dir1=`dirname "$PWD"`
output=`basename "$dir1"`
```

Comment: yes, space is not needed, got copied from above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"$(PWD)"`, you'll want `"${PWD}"`.  The former tries to execute the command PWD, the latter expands to the value of the variable PWD.